Tone.js Sampler throwing "url keys must be the note's pitch" with correct keys
I'm trying to use a tone.js sampler object within p5.js to play notes. I've tested out my environment with basic tone.js synths, but now I want to create a sampler using custom samples. The issue is, no matter what I try, tone is throwing a "url keys must be the note's pitch" error when the sampler constructor is called.
I tried just using the default sampler code from the documentation, but got the exact same results. For scope context, I am defining the sampler variable in the global scope and constructing it in p5's preload, but I have tried multiple different places to load it to no avail. What am I doing wrong?
The default tone.js sampler constructor I am using (with a different callback and variable name):
voice = new Tone.Sampler({
    urls: {
        A1: "A1.mp3",
        A2: "A2.mp3",
    },
    baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
    onload: () => {
        voiceLoaded = true;
    },
});


What version of Tone.js are you using? A [mcve] would be good, especially if p5 is implicated as part of the problem (did you try it without p5 to minimize the issue?)--you can create a runnable stack snippet similar to this. Thanks.
